WebRTC via TURN does not work between IPv4 and IPv6 users
I have the following setup:

User A uses IPv4
User B uses IPv6
TURN server (coturn) is available via both IPv4 and IPv6

When establishing WebRTC connection between two users I can see the exchange of candidates and the testing of each candidate pair, however, none of them are successful. Most of the candidate pairs use relay.
Are there any thoughts on why the connection fails to be established?

Share the code so can better understand

IPv4 and IPv6 are separate, incompatible protocols. An IPv4-only host cannot directly communicate with an IPv6-only host.

Without looking at the candidate addresses, in particular what is being allocated on the TURN server your question is impossible to answer.

@RonMaupin the TURN server is available via IPv4 and IPv6, so I assume user A and B can communicate via relay.

@PhilippHancke I can provide more details, we have WebRTC internals of failed connections. I am having hard time understanding what's a successful candidate pair for such setup should look like.
I assume the pair would contain 2 relay candidates, one with IPv4 address and another one with IPv6 address, is that correct?
Right now I have pairs with 2 relay candidates, but both of them contain IPv4 address.

"_the TURN server is available via IPv4 and IPv6, so I assume user A and B can communicate via relay." Not unless you specifically configure something for that. Most translations mechanisms are deprecated, and the protocols should just be double-stacked. You can check the current RFCs to see the most recent translation methods.

TURN needs to specifically ask for a address family and won't give you two magically. If you have IPv4 relay candidates on both ends why are they not able to talk to each other?

After some more investigation the issue seems to be related to our client's network (user A). When both users use an unrestricted network then everything works as expected, so the TURN configuration seems to be correct to work for IPv4 and IPv6. But what's also interesting is that the WebRTC connection only fails on iOS, not any other platform, with the same internet.
